# Spree Commerce How to upload picture of a product from code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I want to upload picture of a product master variant from code. I can create a simple product using

```
product = Spree::Product.new
product.name = something
product.available_on = Time.now
product.description = something
product.tax_category_id = 1
.......
.......
product.save
```

but when i try to upload product image using an image from my assets it gives me an error of path not found
I followed spree documentation which says i can create an image using

```
img = Spree::Image.create(:attachment => File.open(path), :viewable => product.master)
```

but when i enter image_url "image name" in place of path. it gives an error that /assets/images/imagename no such file or directory

Please let me know if i am missing something very basic here

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `image_url` helper, you should manually build your path:

```
path = Rails.root + 'app/assets/images' + 'my_image_name.png'
Spree::Image.create(:attachment => File.open(path), :viewable => product.master)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me try this and i ll let you know

Comment: Worked like a charm :D